# In the case of a criminal investigation, how does one knows which exchange or wallet service a bitcoin address belongs to?

Tags: blockexplorer, theft

How it was found that the Dao hackers used shapeshift?

In a more practical exemple, how to find that `13qCK9VzJCicXeh47W59rh7A6tfun92Sr5` belongs to https://www.blockchain.com using only block explorer data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranteed way to check.

In most investigations, it is a combination of tracing the money to known addresses (most exchanges and companies consolidate funds into a handful of hot and cold wallets), and exchanges volunteering/sharing information when served with warrants.

Comment: So for my example, how to find `13qCK9VzJCicXeh47W59rh7A6tfun92Sr5` belongs to blockchain.com?

Comment: You probably cannot

Comment: but if someone physically force me to send Bitcoins to such address without showing his/her phone. The police will know that the address belongs to blockchain.com before arresting the guy (of course) but how?

Comment: Again, it is unlikely that you can prove that. Blockchain.com is an explorer, you can pull up any address on that site and show someone a QR Code for it. It is also not an exchange, so no consolidation takes place. The only way to prove it is a blockchain.com address would be to force someone to hand over their account details, and login and check.